# How to update length of list in dart with default value?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

In my app, at many places I have used Lists like this:-

```
List<int> nums = [];
// initializing list dynamically with some values.
nums.length = 12; // increasing length of list
// setting these values afterward using nums[i] at different places.
```

Now after migrating to null-safety obviously `nums.length = 4` is giving me a runtime error, so I was wondering is there any method to set the length of the list with default values such that, after if the length of the list was smaller than before then with new length extra elements are added with some default value.

Note: Of course I know we can use for loop, but I was just wondering if there is any easier and cleaner method than that.

Comment: What do you want the list to be filled with? What determine this default value?

Comment: @julemand101 I want the list to be filled with 0 or any value, as before using it I am going to assign it eventually, I just need to temporarily assign it some value other than null while increasing its length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```dart
extension ExtendList<T> on List<T> {
  void extend(int newLength, T defaultValue) {
    assert(newLength >= 0);

    final lengthDifference = newLength - this.length;
    if (lengthDifference <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    this.addAll(List.filled(lengthDifference, defaultValue));
  }
}

void main() {
  var list = <int>[];
  list.extend(4, 0);
  print(list); // [0, 0, 0, 0];
}
```

Or, if you must set `.length` instead of calling a separate method, you could combine it with a variation of [julemand101's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66588369/) to fill with a specified default value instead of with `null`:

```dart
class ExtendableList<T> with ListMixin<T> {
  ExtendableList(this.defaultValue);

  final T defaultValue;
  final List<T> _list = [];

  @override
  int get length => _list.length;

  @override
  T operator [](int index) => _list[index];

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, T value) {
    if (index >= length) {
      _list.extend(index + 1, defaultValue);
    }
    _list[index] = value;
  }

  @override
  set length(int newLength) {
    if (newLength > length) {
      _list.extend(newLength, defaultValue);
    } else {
      _list.length = newLength;
    }
  }
}
```

(I also made its `operator []=` automatically grow the `ExtendableList` if the specified index is out-of-bounds, similar to JavaScript.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var num = List<int>.generate(4, (i) => i);
```

You can read [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/List.generate.html).

Comment: This will not work, as this will replace all values of ```nums``` I want to increase length with default values.

Comment: If you want to increase it then you can do this `num.addAll([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])` or `num.addAll(List<int>.generate(20, (i) => 0))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `List` in Dart does not have the concept of adding more space while you promise that you are not going to use this new capacity before it is set.

But you can easily make your own `List` implementation which does this:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  List<int> nums = ExtendableList();
  nums.length = 3;

  nums[2] = 1;
  nums[0] = 1;
  nums[1] = 1;

  print(nums); // [1, 1, 1]
  nums.add(2);
  print(nums); // [1, 1, 1, 2]
  print(nums.runtimeType); // ExtendableList<int>
}

class ExtendableList<T> with ListMixin<T> {
  final List<T?> _list = [];

  @override
  int get length => _list.length;

  @override
  T operator [](int index) => _list[index] as T;

  @override
  void operator []=(int index, T value) => _list[index] = value;

  @override
  set length(int newLength) => _list.length = newLength;
}
```

As you can see we are using a null type behind the scene but from the outside it will work like the list contains non-nullable. This only works because we assume the `[]` operator will not be called while a `null` value are in the list (which happens if we extend the list and does not set the value).

I should add that using such a `List` implementation does comes with great risk since you don't get any warning/error from the analyzer if you are using it wrongly.

Comment: Another way to do this would be making a `List` type which contains a default value it should use to fill the list every time it needs to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a list of nullable element to make it longer.

```
List<int?> nums = [];
nums.length = 4; // OK
print(nums); // [null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: Well I need a non-nullable list, if I could I would have preferred something like this ```List<late int> nums = [];```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filled` method. Here `growable` is `false` by default.

```
void main() {
  var a = List<int>.filled(3, 0, growable: true);
  print(a);
  // [0, 0, 0]
}
```

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.filled.html

Comment: well I tried something like this, but the problem is this when I increase length by ```a.length = 5 \\ or something``` it still fills new elements with ```null```.